# Mechanical energy in an harmonic wave and in normal modes

Tags: energy, waves, harmonic-oscillator, normal-modes

I think I miss something about energy of a mechanical wave. 
In absence of dissipation **the mechanical energy transported by an harmonic wave** is constant.

$$E=\frac{1}{2} A^2 \omega^2 m$$

But, while studying normal modes on a rope, I find that **the mechanical energy of a normal mode** (still constant) is equal to

$$E=\frac{1}{4} A^2 \omega^2 m$$

Is the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ really present and why?

($A$ is the amplitude and $m$ is the mass of the rope where the standing wave is created)

Comment: Think about the frequency of a wave at normal modes of vibration through a string

Comment: Define all the symbols. What is $A$?

Comment: $A$ amplitude of motion, $\omega$ angular frequency, $m$ mass?

Comment: @jim yes $m$ is mass

Comment: @Unnikrishnan Thanks, could you specify it a little more?

Comment: At the normal modes of vibration, all the particles of the medium are having a single frequency. $\frac{E}{\rho}=v^2$, where $E$ is the energy of the wave, $\rho$ is the density of the medium, and $v$, the velocity of wave. This came as a result of:  $k=\omega\sqrt{\frac{\rho}{E}}$. Also $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$. Equate both.  
The wave is trnsmitted through the medium as the particle's kinetic energy.  $E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$. So in the case of particles in the rope.....

Comment: Could it be possible that one uses peak to peak amplitude for $A$ and the other center to peak?